# jQuery callback function sync with for loop

Tags: jquery, callback, closures

I am trying to accomplish the followings:

1) A for loop to go through a product list, call a requestCrossDomain() function on each product.

2) function requestCrossDomain() will pass retrieved 3 sets of attribute/description for each product back to the requestCross Domain() function.

3) after requestCrossDomain() function is completed, use a loop closure function to go through the attribute/description results, and create 3 arrays. It's important to know that this function should work on one product at a time, meaning if the for loop is at product[0], then the callback function should work on the attribute/description sets for product[0] as well.

4) use if() statement to find a matching set, and return the array/object index position.

I am stuck with 3), the loop closure didn't seem to return anything in console.log.

```
//step 1)
for (i=0; i<product.length; i++){
   ....       
   requestCrossDomain(arg[i], function(i) {   //step 3)
                                              //need to hold the i value 
      return function() {                     //so the return function() is working on 
         var array = [];                      //the matching product[i]
         $('h4').each(function(j) { 
            array[j] = [];
            var $this = $(this);
            array[i][j] = {
               Attribute: $this.text(),
               Description: $this.next('p').text()
            };

            //step 4)
            if($this.text() == "Attr" && $this.next('p').text() == "Desc") {  
                console.log(i + "-" +j);  //nothing return, no error message
            };
         });          
      }; 

   }(i));
}

//step 2)
function requestCrossDomain(arg, callback) {
   ....
   // 3 sets of attribute/description are constructed here, the html will look like:
   // <div>
   //   <h4>Attribute</h4>
   //   <p>Description</p>
   //   <h4>Attr</h4>
   //   <p>Desc</p>
   //   <h4>A</h4>
   //   <p>D</p>
   // </div>    
   ....
   callback();
}
```

I am guessing I am not fully understanding the callback function with the for loop. My head has been spinning for a few hours, can someone shed a light? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your arrays aren't initializing properly. First of all, did you mean to put

```
array[i] = []; //instead of array[j] right after $('h4').each(function(j) {
```

? because it makes a bit more sense of your code. If you change that and then add

```
array[i][j] = [];
```

as the next line, I believe that you should be good to go.. Let me know.

Also, try placing console.log("Step X"); everywhere you've commented a step to ensure tat step is reached, and see if if all the steps are being reached/which step it breaks.